# Convert absolute path to relative path in Jsp

Tags: java, jsp, path

This my absolute path for save text file. And now I want convert to relative path.

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.jsp"> <%
String jspPath = "C:\\Users\\Farshid\\workspace\\STPT\\WebContent\\file\\title.txt"; //this is my absolute path.
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(jspPath));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;
line = reader.readLine();%> <%=line%></a>
```

And now how I can change to relative path in jsp? and this is my project directory image.
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try with:

```
String path = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRealPath("/file/title.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
```